# Can segmented-control in Ratchet support multiple rows of control-items?

Tags: ratchet-2

Can segmented-control in Ratchet support multiple rows of control-items? The code snippet below will make all the items in one row.

```
<div class="segmented-control">
<a class="control-item active">row1</a>
<a class="control-item">row1</a>
<a class="control-item">row1</a>
<a class="control-item">row1</a>
<a class="control-item">row1</a>

<a class="control-item>row2</a>
<a class="control-item">row2</a>
<a class="control-item">row2</a>
<a class="control-item">row2</a>
<a class="control-item">row2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kindasimple/5ay0zvbg/